# in django models.py how to make remain quantity column of item table change automatically?

Tags: python, django

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sold=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    qtt=0
    def countremain(self):
        qtt=self.quantity-self.sold
        return qqt
    remain=models.IntegerField(qqt)
```

in admin page I can change manually remain value,
but I want to make it automatically.
what I have to change or add to the code above?
Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks Bruno. I got it. What then I could do to change quantity column itself, when sold value increases or decreases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called "denormalization" - if the `remain` value depends on `quantity` and `sold`, you theoretically shouldn't store it in the database (else you may have inconsistent data).

If you still really want to do this, you have to make sure this value is updated by each and any piece of code that touch either `quantity` or `sold`.

The safest way would be a database level trigger (which depends on your db vendor, and is neither a Django nor a Python question actually xD).

Another - less safe - solution is to recompute the value in the model's `save()` method:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    self.remain = self.countremain()
    if update_fields:
        # could be either a tuple or list so we make sure
        # it's a list 
        update_fields = list(update_fields) + ["remain"]  
    super(Item, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Note that this isn't really safe since it won't be triggered by `Queryset.update(...)` - and of course won't be triggered by any other db client.

Comment: thanks Bruno. I got it. What then I could do to change quantity column itself, when sold value increases or decreases?

Comment: @VepaOrazov the proper normalized schema is to keep your "quantity" (number of items in stock) and "sold" (number of items sold) columns and compute the "remain" value from those. This way you always (well, almost, depending on transaction isolation level) have consistent and up to date values. Updating the "quantity" value when "sold" changes is actually the worse thing you could do - it's still unreliable unless using a database trigger, and if anything goes wrong you won't even have a way to recompute the correct value from the initial quantity.

Comment: The general rule is that you should not store what can be computed from already existing data, and if you still want to do it, always consider the denormalized "stored computed value" ("remain" in your example) as a mere cache. And before you go for this, carefully consider the cost of each option vs your most common use cases - iow; depending on what the most common operations are, the cost of maintaining a "cached" value may _or not_ improve performances / ease of use.

Comment: Thank you for extended answer.